# How can I intercept graphql queries?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-graphql

I am using `spring-boot-graphql-starter` in my project. How can I add this interceptor to the graphql queries? This is how I configure the interceptor. However the context value is not filled in the controller. I am using Webflux.

```kotlin
class RequestHeaderInterceptor : WebGraphQlInterceptor {

    private val ccc = "zzz"

    override fun intercept(request: WebGraphQlRequest, chain: WebGraphQlInterceptor.Chain): Mono<WebGraphQlResponse> {
        val value = request.headers.getFirst(ccc)
        request.configureExecutionInput { _, builder ->
            builder.graphQLContext(mapOf("token" to value)).build()
        }
        return chain.next(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it as a bean. From the [WebGraphQlInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current/api/org/springframework/graphql/server/WebGraphQlInterceptor.html) documentation:

> Interceptors are typically declared as beans in Spring configuration and ordered as defined in ObjectProvider.orderedStream().

[GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/0ef87f51020939fef8c06d922dce87eab0f15190/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/reactive/GraphQlWebFluxAutoConfiguration.java#L103) class is responsible for registering all the interceptor beans.